# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /uploads/b056441c611b4e0a9a35.jpg

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I got this error when trying to share image in gmail using `FileProvider`.

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="staging.mytours.co"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

**file_provider_paths.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="uploads" path="." />
</paths>
```

**Java class code:**

```
imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),"staging.mytours.co",new File(Uri.parse(http://staging.mytours.co/uploads/ + tour.getImageCover()).getPath()));
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TOUR:" + tour.getTitle());
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Tour");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```

Have already gone through other solutions from this site but nothing worked in my case.

**Update:**

I have added following function to save image to /data/co.mytours folder in storage.

```
public File DownloadFileFromURL()
    {
        String urlimage = http://staging.mytours.co/uploads/  + tour.getImageCover();
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlimage);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(storagePath
                    + "/data/co.mytours");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

            return storagePath;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", "Exceptio Occured");
            return null;
        }

    }
```

And call this,

```
File imagepath = DownloadFileFromURL();
Uri imageUrishare = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "co.mytours", new File(imagepath.getPath()));
```

But still get a error Attempt to invoke virtual method `java.lang.String java.io.File.getPath()` on a null object reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have an HTTP URL. That is not a local file on the filesystem. You cannot create a `File` object from an HTTP URL.

The simplest thing is to embed the URL as part of your `EXTRA_TEXT` value.

If you really want to attach the image, you will need to:

- Download that image to a file
- Save that file someplace that is configured for your `FileProvider`
- Use the `File` object for your `getUriForFile()` call for use with `EXTRA_STREAM`
- Use the correct MIME type, not `image/*`

Comment: I updated my question. After trying as you said but its getting a  value null.

Comment: @Himanshu: `DownloadFileFromURL()` would appear to be returning `null`.

Comment: Yes I can see that from error but I cannot understand what I did wrong.

Comment: @Himanshu: Presumably, you are catching an `Exception` and then returning `null`. Examine LogCat to see where if there is a Java stack trace associated with your code.

Comment: Yes it is getting value `null` from there. But I don't know where it is throwing exception. It is executing `input.close();` but not returning `storagePath` value.

Comment: finally able to download it to local file. But got problem `Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/co.mytours/files/images/test.jpg.`. The file is present in `data/co.mytours/images/test.jpg`. I am writing `<external-path name="images" path="." />` and authority is `co.mytours`